# Need to count unique observations for three variables taken together

Tags: sql, sas

I have a data set of 5 million observations and three variables of interest are state codes, county codes and tract codes. Now I need to find the total count for distinct observations when taking three variables together. in general one can find a distinct count for a particular variable by:

```
PROC sql;
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(TRACT)) 
    AS COUNT FROM metro1_00;
quit;
```

But I need the unique count like (tract AND county AND state). but unfortunately such options are not available. I'm using SAS 9.3.

Comment: You want unique combinations, so if there are 4 tracts 3 counties 2 states, you have some value between 4 and 4*3*2=24?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to utilize the `group by` statement

```
proc sql noprint;

    create table new_table as
    select distinct count(tract) as COUNT_t
    from metro1_00
    group by tract, county, state
    ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just group by?

```
SELECT TRACT, COUNTY, STATE, count(*) FROM metro1_00
GROUP BY TRACT, COUNTY, STATE
```

If you really just want the distinct of the combination TRACT, COUNTY, STATE, you may be able to use a subquery/inline view. It looks like sas [supports these.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0zncz0umdx2tdn1m6k5tvdqwzed.htm)

```
SELECT count(*) 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TRACT, COUNTY, STATE FROM metro1_00) 
          as subq(TRACT, COUNTY, STATE)
```

Comment: Yes, that would work (and doesn't require the (Tract, County , State) part at the end - those would be automatically used.).

Comment: that worked exactly the way i wanted. thank you all.